# Add childrens of a div on different positions in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to add in array props of childrens of a parent div like so :

```
<div>
<img id="1">
<img id="2">
<img id="3">
<img id="4">
</div>
```

So in the array it should be `a = [1,2,3,4];`

What i have done so far:

```
lengthOfSmallImgs = element.children('div').children('img').length;
        for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfSmallImgs; i++) {
            tags = [];
            tags[i] = element.children('div').children('img');
            console.log(tags[i]);
        }
```

But unfortunately, the console looks like: `a=[1, undefined, undefined, undefined]`, and the `a[0] = [img#1, img#2, img#3, img#4, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: a].`

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: `$('div img').each(function(){tags.push(this.id)})`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/szfwk3xe/

Answer (score 1):

```
tags[i] = element.children('div').children('img');
```

In this line. If this `element.children('div').children('img');` returns an array since you check its length on the first line, the correct way should be something like this `tags[i] = element.children('div').children('img')[i];`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is:

```
tags[i] = element.children('div').children('img');
```

instead of:

```
tags[i] = element.children('div').children('img')[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the array inside the loop.
Put

```
tags = [];
```

outside the for loop.

Edit: The complete code should look like this:

```
lengthOfSmallImgs = element.children('div').children('img').length;
tags = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfSmallImgs; i++) {
    tags[i] = element.children('div').children('img')[i].id;
}
console.log(tags); // Outputs Array ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```